# no such table: wagtailcore_site

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, wagtail

I'm hosting two websites on ubuntu server and both having postgresql, the first one is working prefect but the second give me this error

> no such table: wagtailcore_site Request Method:   GET
>
> Django Version:   2.2.10 Exception
>
> Type: OperationalError Exception Value:    no such table:
>
> wagtailcore_site Exception
>
> Location: /home/project2/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py
>
> in execute, line 383 Python
>
> Executable:   /home/project2/.venv/bin/python3.7m Python Version: 3.7.3

database settings for first website:

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'project_one',
        'USER': 'project_one',
        'PASSWORD': '123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

database settings for second website:

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'project_two',
        'USER': 'project_two',
        'PASSWORD': '123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

from the error it seems that django try to run sqllite instead of postgresql, I dont know why !

***Notes:***

- `python manage.py migrate` command working without any problem whith the second database.
- SQL lite is working, the problem only with postgresql in the second project.
- I'm using nginx and gunicorn.

I think the problem maybe with the `HOST` and `PORT` settings in both settings maybe they conflicting each other? ( I try change the port and host also but didn't solve it)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I have two gunicorn files for both websites and I was restarting gunicorn for first websites not the second one.

Which mean there is no errors in the code above.. The problem only in restarting gunicorn.

Answer (score 1):

Django 3.2 will also call this exception while integrating wagtail.
If you haven't made migrations before adding the core url, youll get this error.

django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: wagtailcore_site

If you just make migrations it should fix this issue